# How can I order data from several columns into a new sheet alphabetically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I order data that I have separated in different columns into a new sheet, and order those alphabetically? I would prefer them to be in different columns (one per letter) but if not, having them in a single column alphabetically will do it anyways.
Pictures as an example of what I want:

The first sheet will have the data separated in different columns according to a category
[image]

The second sheet will be the 'table of content' taking all the data from sheet 1 and placing order

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I realize the OP did not include Office 365, but with the dynamic array formula:

```
=LET(y,Sheet1!$A$2:$C$6,z,SEQUENCE(ROWS(y)*COLUMNS(y),,0),x,INDEX(y,INT(z)/3+1,MOD(z,3)+1),SORT(FILTER(x,LEFT(x)=A$1)))
```

Put that in A2 and copy over 26 columns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will be quite complex with formulas. You'll probably need VBA for that.

in pseudo code

```
for each cell in the source sheet
   if the cell has content
      get the first letter
      copy the cell into the corresponding column on the second sheet
   end if
next cell
' now all the data is in alphabetical columns on the second sheet
' next, sort each column
for the first 26 columns in the target sheet
  sort the data in that column
next column
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Power Query` available in Excel 2010+

- Select some cell in the table
- Data / Get&Transform / From Table/Range
- Open the Advanced editor and make note of the Table name in Line 2
- Paste the MCode below into the Advanced Editor

  - Change the resultant line 2 to reflect the correct Table name
- Examine the steps in the Applied Steps window to see how this was done.

---

- Sort the entries
- Unpivot to make it into a single column
- Group by the first letter of each entry
- Extract all the entries that correspond to a letter into multiple columns
- Transpose the result

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table16"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"GEO", type text}, {"DEPORTE", type text}, {"POLITICA", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Grouper", each Text.Start([Value],1)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Grouper"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Value=text, Grouper=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", "Custom.2", "Custom.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Custom.1", type text}, {"Custom.2", type text}, {"Custom.3", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns1"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"A", type text}, {"B", type text}, {"C", type text}, {"L", type text}, {"R", type text}, {"S", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

[image]

If you must use Excel 2007, which does not have Power Query, here is VBA code which will do the job.

- Collect the data in a Dictionary where the Key is the Alphabet letter, and the contents is an array list of the items that start with that letter.
- The array list is handy because it is easily sorted, although other sorting algorithms could be used.
- Be sure to change `wsRes`, `wsSrc`, and `rRes` to reflect where you want the Source and Results worksheets and ranges.  Also check that `vSrc` will refer to the proper data source range.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub reOrder()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc, vRes, V, W
    Dim Dict As Object, AL As Object, alKeys As Object
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, sKey As String * 1
    
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet13")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet13")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 15)
    
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
End With

'Gather the data
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
      If Trim(vSrc(I, J)) <> "" Then
        sKey = vSrc(I, J)
        If Not Dict.exists(sKey) Then
            Set AL = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
            AL.Add vSrc(I, J)
            Dict.Add sKey, AL
        Else
            Dict(sKey).Add vSrc(I, J)
        End If
      End If
    Next J
Next I

'Size vRes
I = 0
For Each V In Dict
    I = IIf(I > Dict(V).Count, I, Dict(V).Count)
Next V

ReDim vRes(0 To I, 1 To Dict.Count)

'Sort the dictionary keys
Set alKeys = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each V In Dict.keys
    alKeys.Add V
Next V
alKeys.Sort

J = 0
For Each V In alKeys
    J = J + 1
        
        'Column Header
        vRes(0, J) = V
        I = 0
        
            'Data
            For Each W In Dict(V)
                I = I + 1
                vRes(I, J) = W
            Next W
Next V

'Write the results to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```